# matplotlib: Why are the dates stuck together?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, stock

I'm currently analyzing stocks. Therefore, I'd like to plot their price in respect to the time. For this purpose, I have this following function:

```
def plot_pandas(column,start, end, y_label = 'USD'):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols = 1)

      # title
    plt.title(column.columns[0])
    
      # x_axis  
    plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18)
    
    axes.set_xlim(start, end)
    years = mdates.YearLocator()   # every year
    months = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
    years_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')

    axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
    axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(years_fmt)
    axes.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
    axes.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    
      # y_axis  
    plt.ylabel(column.columns[0] + ' ' + y_label, fontsize=18)
    
      # frame_size
    fig.set_figheight(8)
    fig.set_figwidth(15)
    plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
      # data
    plt.plot(column)

    plt.show()
```

But as you can see on the image: The dates are stuck together. Can anybody help?[image]

Comment: have you tried without specifying the font size?

Comment: Could you create a reproducible example? It is very unclear how your data looks like, what type, how many years, ....  Which libraries are you using? Did you try plotting a small subset to get an idea how the format looks like? ....?

Comment: @JohanC Sorry for not having responded. I have been on vacation. Actually, I'm plotting a date series. My actually question is: How to prevent the overlapping of the x lable

Comment: Well, as you didn't create a reproducible example, it's very hard to answer your actual question. My actual question is: please, create a reproducible example. How did you create the "date series"? There are many ways.  It should be in pandas or in matplotlib format to let them automatically set adequate labeling.